# Mounting and Unmounting component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-lifecycle

i'm currently executing `this.props.navigation.navigate('myView')` using ***react-navigation***.

But when i leave and enter quickly to that view, in some cases a strange behavior occurs in the **react-native life cycle**.

**My logs:**

**When works normally:*

```
- Navigate to `myView`
  componentWillMount >>>>>>>>> 

- Back from `myView`
  componentWillUnmount >>>>>>>>>
```

**When i navigate quickly:*

```
- Navigate to `myView`
  componentWillMount >>>>>>>>> 

- Back from `myView`
  componentWillUnmount >>>>>>>>> 

- Quick navigate to `myView`
  componentWillMount >>>>>>>>> 
  componentWillMount >>>>>>>>> 
  componentWillUnmount >>>>>>>>>
```

> At the end of this case, the unmount is running and leaving the view in an incorrect state.

Comment: I believe this issue has been solved in v3, which version are you running?

Comment: :O.. thanks.. i'm running `2.0.4`. Is recommended upgrade to `v3`? I'm asking because is an `alpha` version. Anyway, I'll try it and if that version solves the problem, I'll consider leaving the update.

Comment: The update is pretty straightforward, you only need to add one extra step in your main routes config.

Comment: ok, thanks. The truth is that what worries me is the stability of that version, not the changes I have to make in my code.

Comment: Which version of react are you using? componentWillMount is going to be deprecated and there is new life-cycle events implemented. For more info please check [React Component API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

Comment: `"react": "16.0.0", "react-native": "0.51.0"`. This will continue to work until the `17` version and I'm on the 16. This should have no impact on the problem in question